# Reverse flex direction and div scrolling overflow indication

Tags: flexbox, overflow

I have used the resources here on my favourite site *stack**overflow*** to find 2 different solutions... Firstly I make use of `flex-direction: column-reverse;` to have the div scrolled all the way to the end when the page loads. Secondly, I add some shading to the div to indicate there is some overflow content; however, I can't get the 2 solutions to work together. The shading works great; however, now that I have implemented the flex-direction, the shading is on the wrong end of the `<div>`... scroll it all the way to either the top or bottom and you'll see the shading is on the non-overflow side... How do I fix that.

```css
.conversation_div {
  overflow: auto;
  min-width:300px;
  max-width:450px;
  max-height:400px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;


  background:
    /* Shadow covers */
    linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0)),
    linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), white 70%) 0 100%,
    
    /* Shadows */
    radial-gradient(50% 0, farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(50% 100%,farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)) 0 100%;
  background:
    /* Shadow covers */
    linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0)),
    linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), white 70%) 0 100%,
    
    /* Shadows */
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 0, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 100%, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)) 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: 100% 40px, 100% 40px, 100% 14px, 100% 14px;
  
  /* Opera doesn't support this in the shorthand */
  background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
  
}

.date_style_1
{
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  clear:both;
  padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.date_style_2
{
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
  margin-left:5px;
  clear:both;
  padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.style_1
{
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  clear:both;
  background-color:#1e73be;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  border:2px solid #1e73be;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
  padding:2px;
}
.style_2
{
  float:right;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  clear:both;
  background-color:white;
  color:#1e73be;
  font-weight:bold;
  border:2px solid #1e73be;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class='conversation_div'>
    <div sytle='width:100%;'>
        <div class='date_style_1'>June 10, 2023 01:05:50
        </div>
        <div class='style_1'>Item 11 - Style 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div sytle='width:100%;'>
        <div class='date_style_1'>June 10, 2023 01:05:45
        </div>
        <div class='style_1'>Item 10 - Style 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div sytle='width:100%;'>
        <div class='date_style_1'>June 10, 2023 01:05:40
        </div>
        <div class='style_1'>Item 9 - Style 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div sytle='width:100%;'>
        <div class='date_style_2'>June 10, 2023 01:05:35
        </div>
        <div class='style_2'>Item 8 - Style 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div sytle='width:100%;'>
        <div class='date_style_1'>June 10, 2023 01:05:30
        </div>
        <div class='style_1'>Item 7 - Style 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div sytle='width:100%;'>
        <div class='date_style_1'>June 10, 2023 01:05:25
        </div>
        <div class='style_1'>Item 6 - Style 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div sytle='width:100%;'>
        <div class='date_style_2'>June 10, 2023 01:05:20
        </div>
        <div class='style_2'>Item 5 - Style 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div sytle='width:100%;'>
        <div class='date_style_2'>June 10, 2023 01:05:15
        </div>
        <div class='style_2'>Item 4 - Style 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div sytle='width:100%;'>
        <div class='date_style_2'>June 10, 2023 01:05:10
        </div>
        <div class='style_2'>Item 3 - Style 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div sytle='width:100%;'>
        <div class='date_style_1'>June 10, 2023 01:05:05
        </div>
        <div class='style_1'>Item 2 - Style 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div sytle='width:100%;'>
        <div class='date_style_1'>June 10, 2023 01:05:00
        </div>
        <div class='style_1'>Item 1 - Style 1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```